# Email attachment save

Tags: python, python-2.7, email-attachments

I'm try to parse email with attached pdf files

```
def get_files(poruka):
    pdfs = []
    if poruka.is_multipart():
        for part in poruka.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'application/pdf':
                data = part.get_payload()
                temppdf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', -1)
                temppdf.write(base64.b64decode(data))
                pdfs.append(temppdf)

    return pdfs
```

It works but in `pdfs` I have file instances. What I try to do is to save a files with his original name inside folder named storage.

When I try `open(temppdf, 'wb').write(temppdf.get_payload(decode=True))` I got error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found`.

Also how to get pdfs[0] filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you are trying to open a file object and not a file name.  You can try `open(temppdf.name)` but that may not work (it's not guaranteed to across all platforms).  As of Python 2.6 you can specify `delete=False` on the [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) call, though, and then opening `temppdf.name` should work fine.